# .csv file handling single line at a time using php

Tags: php, file, csv, logging

I use .csv file to keep log whether the file is uploaded to server or not. Log file is as shown in below :

*09:40:51,kapilbastu,1001,201407290940041001msg.mp3,201407290940041001vdc.mp3,137,Not_syn
09:44:30,kapilbastu,1001,201407290943351001msg.mp3,201407290943351001vdc.mp3,136,Not_syn
09:46:25,Other,1001,201407290945481001msg.mp3,201407290945481001vdc.mp3,137,Syn
09:47:13,Other,1001,201407290946411001msg.mp3,201407290946411001vdc.mp3,136,Syn
09:47:50,Other,1001,201407290947191001msg.mp3,201407290947191001vdc.mp3,136,Not_syn
11:46:01,kapilbastu,1001,201407291145101001msg.mp3,201407291145101001vdc.mp3,137,Not_syn
13:58:14,kapilbastu,1001,201407291357121001msg.mp3,201407291357121001vdc.mp3,136,Syn*

Sometime file is sync but sometime file can't sync due to Internet problem as we can see in the 'G' column of the log file. I need to read this log file and have to upload file *.mp3 one by one. For that i run php script in crontab that have to read file in each line and upload files. If the file is  uploaded successfully then only "Not-syn" field need to change to "Syn". If the line has "Syn" already,it do nothing and move to next line.

I wrote following php script:

```
$a=6;
if (($handle = fopen("/tmp/newfile.csv", "ar+")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        if ($data[$a] == "Not_syn") {
            $date = $data[$a - 6];
            $from= $data[$a - 5];
            $phoneNumber = $data[$a - 4];
            $vdc = $data[$a - 3];
            $msg = $data[$a - 2];
            $postTo = $data[$a - 1];

            $flag=upload_function( $date, $from, $phoneNumber, $vdc, $msg, $postTo )                
            if($flag)
            {  
                $detail = array($date, $from, $phoneNumber, $msg, $vdc, $postTo, "Syn"); 
                fputcsv($handle , $detail);
            }
            else
            {
                $detail = array($date, $from, $phoneNumber, $msg, $vdc, $postTo, "Not_syn"); 
                fputcsv($handle , $detail);

            }

                return true;
            } 
            else 
            {
                $detail = array($date, $from, $phoneNumber, $msg, $vdc, $postTo, "Not_syn"); 
                fputcsv($handle , $detail);

                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

fclose($handle);

which is rubbish programming.
How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: when i run it all the log file data are randomly scatter. it works fine for only first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got answer of my own question.

```
$myfile = 'newfile.csv';

$file_read = fopen($myfile, 'r');
$data = array();

while ($line = fgetcsv($file_read, 1000)) {
    $Col_No = count($line) - 1;
    if (strcasecmp(trim($line[$Col_No]), 'Syn') == 0) {
        $data[] = $line;
        continue;
    }

    $date = $line[$Col_No - 6];
    $from = $line[$Col_No - 5];
    $phoneNumber = $line[$Col_No - 4];
    $vdc = $line[$Col_No - 3];
    $msg = $line[$Col_No - 2];
    $postTo = $line[$Col_No - 1];

    $flag = upload( $date, $from,$phoneNumber,$vdc,$msg, $postTo); //function return true if file uploaded successfully otherwise return false.

    for ($i = 0, $k = count($line); $i < $k; $i++) {
        if ($flag) {
            $line[$Col_No] = 'Syn';
        }
    }
    $data[] = $line;
}

fclose($file_read);

$file_write = fopen($myfile, 'w');
foreach ($data as $line) {
    fputcsv($file_write, $line);
}
fclose($file_write);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do:

```
if (($handle = fopen("log.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {  /* Read csv log file */
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
      /* Compare the value in column 'G' (last valid index in the $data array) to 'Syn'
       * If the value in the 'G' column is 'Syn', skip it and move to the next line
       * Function used is strcasecmp() - comparison is case in-sensitive
       */
      if(strcasecmp(trim($data[count($data)-1]), 'Syn') == 0){
         continue; 
      }
    /* I'm just printing out the values here BUT HERE IS WHERE YOU SHOULD PUT YOUR FILE UPLOAD CODE LOGIC */
        echo $data[0] . '<br/>'; 
        echo $data[1] . '<br/>';
        echo $data[2] . '<br/>';
        echo $data[3] . '<br/>';
        echo $data[4] . '<br/>'; 
        echo $data[5] . '<br/>';
        echo $data[6] . '<br/>';
        echo '<br/>';    

    }
}
fclose($handle);
```

Hope it helps. Goodluck!

Comment: this code only skip the line which has "Syn" in G column. but i also need to change "Not_syn" to "Syn" when files are successfully uploaded.